# C# - design to parse and write csv and manipulating data

Tags: c#

I've designed the below code for one of the requirement. I have to write different tests for the code and I would need feedback on where I can improve the design.

Requirement:

1. Read the customer details from csv, calculate his average expenses on different items on yearly and write to csv again.
2. Read the customer details from csv, calculate his total expenses on faimly and write to csv again.

As both the ExpenseCalculator uses CsvReaderWriter function, is it better to create the abstract class which implements csvReaderWriter functionality and derive from abstract class or is it better to use Interface?

```
    public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Expenses { get; set; }
    // other details
}

public interface ICsvReaderWriter<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ParseCsv(string filePath);
    void WriteCsv(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers);
}

public class ReaderWriter : ICsvReaderWriter<Customer>
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> ParseCsv(string filePath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteCsv(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IExpenseCalculator
{
    void CalculateExpenses(string filePath);
}

public class ItemExpenseCalculator : IExpenseCalculator
{
    private readonly ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> _csvReaderWriter;
    public ItemExpenseCalculator(ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> csvReaderWriter)
    {
        this._csvReaderWriter = csvReaderWriter;
    }

    public void CalculateExpenses(string filePath)
    {
        var customers = _csvReaderWriter.ParseCsv(filePath);
        // do manipulation
        _csvReaderWriter.WriteCsv(filePath, customers);
    }
}

public class FamilyExpenseCalculator: IExpenseCalculator
{
    private readonly ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> _csvReaderWriter;

    public FamilyExpenseCalculator(ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> csvReaderWriter)
    {
        this._csvReaderWriter = csvReaderWriter;
    }

    public void CalculateExpenses(string filePath)
    {
        var customers = _csvReaderWriter.ParseCsv(filePath);
        // do manipulation
        _csvReaderWriter.WriteCsv(filePath, customers);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private void Main()
    {
        IExpenseCalculator itemExpenseCalculator = new ItemExpenseCalculator(new ReaderWriter());
        itemExpenseCalculator.CalculateExpenses(@"D:\");

        IExpenseCalculator familyExpenseCalculator = new FamilyExpenseCalculator(new ReaderWriter());
        familyExpenseCalculator.CalculateExpenses(@"D:\");
    }
}
```

Comment: does this code work as expected?

Comment: I just want the design to be reviewed. Do I still need to post the code? and why it's already -1

Comment: Isn't there a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site?

Comment: this is the comment when I post the code in code review, "The sites scope is only to review code. We don't review design. For design related question you can check out programmers.se but make sure to read their help center first to check if your question is on topic there". Thanks for your comment. Really frustrating to move across different sites. If needed, I will delete my post

Comment: see [Design Review: on-topic or not?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260) "generally, design review type questions are on-topic. However, the problem is how broad they are. My concern for this type of question is that most of them may be more suited to a discussion environment. I do think that there are good design review questions, but they need to be clear and specific and not soliciting general feedback..."

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel: Use a library for CSV parsing/writing so you can focus on your domain problem(s).

Comment: @Laoujin it's not clear whether he actually wants to implement parsing from the ground up, his classes could be just wrappers around some library calls (adding custom error handling, for instance). If not, then you're definitely right. Parsing CSV isn't nearly as easy as it might seem!

Comment: @KonradMorawski- I have to implement the parsing from scratch, so I need to create separate classes for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's not a very good design, because it doesn't adhere to [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) .

   - `ICsvReaderWriter` has two responsibilities, as the name itself indicates. I wouldn't lump them together into one class. Besides, the Reader / Writer distinction is sort of idiomatic in the .NET world (think `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` - you won't find a `StreamReaderWriter` in the standard library).
   - `IExpenseCalculator` doesn't only calculate expenses, which is quite easy to tell because its method takes a `filePath` parameter. The Single Responsibility Principle states that a class should have one, and only one reason to change. Your `IExpenseCalculator`, however, has several potential reasons to change. It's not just if expenses are to be calculated differently, but also if the output of these calculations has to be retrieved or persisted differently... or not persisted but passed further along etc. And you can't easily unit test your `ItemExpenseCalculator` (to ensure that it works), because it pulls its input from the file system and pushes the output there as well.
2. Inheritance hierarchy seems to be upside down to me, too. The interface is `ICsvReaderWriter`, but the implementation is simply a `ReaderWriter`. So the base interface is more specific than the child class, because its name already defines the concrete format, whereas the derived class sports a universal name omitting technical details.

   Why would the interface care about the storage format? I'd expect this to be designed the other way round: a generic `IWriter` interface that could be implemented by a concrete `CsvWriter`, or an `XmlWriter`, or a `JsonWriter`  if there is a need.

   See the [principle of abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_abstraction) for reference. Key takeaway: *"the higher the level, the less detail. The lower the level, the more detail."*
3. There's also a slip-up in the interface definition:

   ```
    public interface ICsvReaderWriter<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> ParseCsv(string filePath);
        void WriteCsv(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers);
    }
   ```

   Shouldn't that rather be

   ```
   void WriteCsv(string filePath, IEnumerable<T> objects);
   ```
4. Naming is a bit off. If the interface is a `Reader`, not a `Parser`, why is the method named `Parse`? It introduces semantic noise. Synonyms are good in creative writing, but in software development we should strive for unambiguity.
5. And a minor remark... not really a design issue, just a matter of code style.

   ```
   private readonly ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> _csvReaderWriter;
   ```

   ```
   public ItemExpenseCalculator(ICsvReaderWriter<Customer> csvReaderWriter)
   {
       this._csvReaderWriter = csvReaderWriter;
   }
   ```

   Some prefer to prefix fields with an underscore (`_csvReaderWriter`), some don't like it and then they have to explicitly use `this` to differentiate between fields and parameters of the same name. To each his own, it's a matter of taste and consistency. However doing both at once makes no sense. It's like wearing belt and braces. If you're referencing the current object explicitly with `this`, what purpose does the underscore serve?

Comment: How do I change the ItemExpenseCalculator then? Can you give some ideas.

Comment: @SabVenkat I don't know what it does exactly, but one step towards a better design would be to make it accept "pure" data (Customers) and spit out processed data at the end. But leave the file system out of it. The class wouldn't care if they were only just read from a csv file, nor what is going to happen with them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I will remove the file system out of it and call it from Main. But rather than calling it from Main is there any way I can do it??

Comment: @SabVenkat yes, it's actually preferable if you wrapped it all in another class (not Main). A class taking an `IReader`, `IWriter` and an `IExpenseCalculator`, and putting them together to use. Of course if it's just a one-off, throw-away program, having clean design doesn't matter very much, but since you're asking about it...